# Moshi JSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, moshi

Experimenting with "Moshi" tonight, Square's JSON parsing library.
Here's my basic attempt that mirrors [an example in their README](https://github.com/square/moshi). I haven't gotten it working no matter what I try! I'd appreciate more eyes/any ideas on it.

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
JsonAdapter<Leagues> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Leagues.class);
Leagues result = jsonAdapter.fromJson(rawJson);
```

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/es0329/a0c4fc93725a8a9610996ce1da4d49f9) of relevant files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed!!** The `leagues` property in `Leagues.java` should've been of type **`Map<String, League>`**.